# Bootstrap: How to create col separators

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, css-selectors, separator

**Edit**

I am using the Bootstrap grid framework. What is the best approach to create vertical col separators using pure CSS?
See my code below:

---

**original question**

I am using the Bootstrap grid framework. Apart from the common `.col-*-*` classes I am also using the `.col-*-push-*` and `.col-*-pull-*` classes to reorder my cols with increasing viewport width.

I want to divide the cols in the middle by a thin border, using this SASS-code:

```
/* Hide any overflowing columns, applied to .row */
.gutter-border {
  overflow: hidden;

  [class^="col-"],
  [class*=" col-"] {
    border-left: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
    padding-left: $grid-gutter-width / 2;

    /* Equal height hack */
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;

        &:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
        padding-left: $grid-gutter-width / 2;
        }
    }
    .col-xs-#{$grid-columns} {
        @media (max-width: $screen-sm) {
        border-right: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
        }
    }
    .col-sm-#{$grid-columns} {
        @media (min-width: $screen-sm) and (max-width: $screen-md) {
        border-right: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
        }
    }
    .col-md-#{$grid-columns} {
        @media (min-width: $screen-md) and (max-width: $screen-lg) {
        border-right: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
        }
    }
    .col-lg-#{$grid-columns} {
        @media (min-width: $screen-lg) {
        border-right: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course using the push and pull classes the `:last-child` selector won't work as the columns are pushed and pulled with the `left` and `right` attribute:

```
/* Excerpt from Bootstrap Sass port, /_mixins/_grid-framework.scss, line 33ff */
@mixin calc-grid-column($index, $class, $type) {
  @if ($type == width) and ($index > 0) {
    .col-#{$class}-#{$index} {
      width: percentage(($index / $grid-columns));
    }
  }
  @if ($type == push) and ($index > 0) {
    .col-#{$class}-push-#{$index} {
      left: percentage(($index / $grid-columns));
    }
  }
  @if ($type == pull) and ($index > 0) {
    .col-#{$class}-pull-#{$index} {
      right: percentage(($index / $grid-columns));
    }
  }
}
```

So, is there any possibility using SASS/CSS to select not the last child in the node but the last child displayed?
Or must I develop a jQuery solution, what would be quite easy?

Comment: The problem is there may be no schema that could be relied on to select the last child displayed, so If you can it'll be easier to add a custom class to your last child displayed manually to html.

Comment: The CSS last child will always be the last element in the nodelist of the DOM. You'd probably need to do the jQuery solution so that you can inspect the positions of the elements involved. That or keep a custom attribute applied to the element you regard as being "last" and apply a CSS selector to the custom attribute. ie. `<tag data-lastcolumn="true">` and `tag[data-lastcolumn="true"] { }`